# Zend2 - Doctrine2: Create new entity with Many-to-One relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a "Record" entity that can have N "Comments".

This is the setup for those two entities:

**Record**

```
<entity name="Application\Model\Record" table="record">
    <id name="recordID" type="integer">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>
    <many-to-one field="user" target-entity="Application\Model\User">
        <join-column name="userID" referenced-column-name="userID" />
    </many-to-one>
    <field name="status" type="string" nullable="false" />
    <one-to-many field="comments" target-entity="Application\Model\RecordComment" mapped-by="record" />
</entity>
```

**RecordComment**

```
<entity name="Application\Model\RecordComment" table="recordComment">
    <id name="recordCommentID" type="integer">
        <generator strategy="AUTO" />
    </id>
    <indexes>
        <index columns="userID" />
        <index columns="recordID" />
    </indexes>
    <field name="comment" type="text" nullable="false" />
    <field name="time" type="integer" length="11" nullable="false" />
    <many-to-one field="user" target-entity="Application\Model\User">
        <join-column name="userID" referenced-column-name="userID" />
    </many-to-one>
    <many-to-one field="record" target-entity="Application\Model\Record" inversed-by="comments">
        <join-column name="recordID" referenced-column-name="recordID" />
    </many-to-one>        
</entity>
```

I'm struggling on how to create a form to create a new record, in which to add multiple comments.

If I skip the comments, it is pretty straight forward to create a new record that has the "status" field, and is linked to a user. However, when I try to add comments to it at the same time, everything falls apart.

I have created two fieldsets, one of the comment and one for the record. However, how do I link the recordComment to the record? I would have thought that the link would happen automatically, since the recordComment is being added to the record, but on the database the recordID field is NULL.

Here's my RecordComment fieldset:

```
class RecordCommentFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    protected $objectManager;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('recordComment');

        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;

        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($this->objectManager, 'Application\Model\RecordComment'))
             ->setObject(new RecordComment());     

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'comment',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Textarea',
        ));
    }

    public function getInputFilterSpecification()
    {
        return array(
            'comment' => array(
                'required' => true,
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

### UPDATE

I was wrong in assuming Doctrine was going to make the connection directly.
The comments are actually added to the record, after:

```
$form->setData($this->request->getPost());
```

However, I have to manually iterate through the comments and assign the record back to them before persisting the record:

```
foreach($record->getComments() as $comment){
    $comment->setRecord($record);
}
```

Is there another way to solve this, without manually iterating though the elements?
What's the point of adding the elements into my entity, if they reverse connection is not created?

Comment: did you consider using doctrineobjectselect in the form? that way you could just give the form those comments and you'll have them in your data 2 that way

Comment: but in order to use DoctrineObjectSelect you already need to have the comment created.
If you look at my RecordComment definition that is not possible because it needs a recordID to exist, you cannot have a comment without a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this a while ago, but here's how I fixed it.

When defining the One-to-Many relationship, make sure to add the cascade persist option. That will make sure that your sub elements are properly attached to your object and persisted along with it.

```
<one-to-many field="comments" target-entity="Application\Model\RecordComment" mapped-by="record">
    <cascade>
        <cascade-persist />
    </cascade>
</one-to-many>
```

There is no need to iterate through all the comments, unless you need to add any other relationships (user posting, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing right. At least that's what the [doctrine documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) says (using a User-Comment example):

> Even if you persist a new User that contains our new Comment this code would fail if you removed the call to EntityManager#persist($myFirstComment). Doctrine 2 does not cascade the persist operation to all nested entities that are new as well.

However I would do the way the documentation suggests, just persisting the comments:

```
(...)
foreach( $record->getComments() as $comment ) {
    $comment->persist( $comment );
}
```